# Subgroups of top cohomological dimension

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a geometrically finite group, i.e. there exists a finite CW complex of type $K(G,1)$.
By Serre's Theorem, every finite-index subgroup $H$ of $G$ satisfies $cd(H)=cd(G)$, but what about the opposite implication?

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $cd(H)=cd(G)$, does it already follow that $H$ has finite index? If not, are there additional conditions on $G$ under which this would be true?

Comment: Think of some simple examples such as free groups of rank at least 2 or, more generally,  free products. For your 2nd question, Think about Poincare duality groups.

Comment: Thank you, Moishe! May I ask where I can find a reference for the statement for Poincare duality groups?

Comment: Probably in Brown's book.

Comment: The result for Poincaré duality groups is due to Strebel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the sake of completeness:

1. Is false, just take the free product $G=H\star H$, where $H$ is a (geometrically finite) group of cohomological dimension $n$, $0<n<\infty$.
2. This is true when $G$ is a Poincare Duality group, you can find it in exercise 6 (with a hint), section 10 of chapter 8 of Ken Brown's book "Cohomology of Groups." The fact is purely cohomological, you do not need geometric finiteness.

A complete proof can be found in
*Strebel, R.*, [**A remark on subgroups of infinite index in Poincaré duality groups**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02567371), Comment. Math. Helv. 52, 317-324 (1977). [ZBL0365.20040](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0365.20040).